# Karma does not detect new test files

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I use karma as test runner for my Javascript test with enabled autoWatch option. Every time a test file changes karma reruns the tests, how expected. But when I create a new test file karma does not detect this file automatically until I restart karma manually, although the new file matches the watched file pattern in the karma configuration.

How karma has to be configured in order to detect new test files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma config is loaded only at startup. So you need to wrap karma in some other runner.

For example: you can use `gulp`.

`gulp.watch` can... watch for file changes and rerun karma from scratch (in order to reload the config).

For further details about implementation you could take a look at this:
[gulp-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma)

Comment: I did not made any change in the config, the watched test file pattern did not changed. Do you mean karma expands the file patterns to the really exiting single files only at startup?