# Angular test runner does not detect new files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've just created a new Angular application (v.16) and started unit-test runner via `ng test`. Problem is test runner does not detect newly added spec files.

Test runner works, finds all spec files and runs tests from them. If I change some application file or `spec.ts` file it rebuilds application and rerun tests.

However, if I add a completely new `.spec.ts`-file to application, test runner does not run tests from it. It detects if I change that file, rebuilds application, but does not execute any tests from newly added file. To see it I have to stop test runner and restart it - after that everything works fine.

It's a bit annoying restarting test runner each time new spec is added, so I wonder if anyone has experienced similar problem and knows what to do in this case.

Comment: Have you checked the `tsconfig.spec.json` file entry point of the spec.ts files or folder? You might be creating a test which is not in that path because we don't know the the file structure of your files.

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ this can't be the case because it works after restarting the test runner

Comment: `ng test` uses karma under the hood. I found a similar question for karma: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42804232/5470544 Apparently, karma generates the list of spec files at startup and does not detect new files. This question is not a duplicate as the given solution does not work with the Angular CLI.